# Deploy PHP Project Using Bash?

Tags: bash, deployment

My hosting service just informed me that they don't have Git installed on any of their servers. I am at a loss as to how I am going to deploy a project there. My only option is Bash, it seems. Is it possible to deploy a project using bash only? Help is much, much appreciated.
Regards

Comment: Why don't you just copy the PHP files to your host using scp or FTP?

Comment: You can certainly deploy a project using Bash, but you may want to check out Phing (a build and deploy tool) written in PHP http://phing.info. It includes features that support working with Git ftp and much more.

Comment: @Tichodroma, yes I can always do that but that's very tiresome job, if you have changed huge number of files inside different directories.

Comment: @SteveRobillard, Phing looks great. Will definitely give it a shot. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same issues, I found the deploy option in http://beanstalkapp.com to be excellent, you can setup deploy via SFTP/FTP from your GIT/SVN repo.
And even deploy in staging.

Comment: But abhisek didn't write about his code being inside a Git repository.